# Convergent or Divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, divergent-series

Determine if the series converges or diverges: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n \left|\sin(n)\right|} = $$

We know that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}i = \text{Divergent}
$$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^1 \ln(i )= 0
$$

How to solve this?

Comment: you need to remove 1 from right hand side of first eq. The other two can be reworded too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way: also note $\frac{\log n }{n|\sin n|} \geq \frac{\log n}{n}$. Now look at $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log n }{n}$. By intergral test if the integral diverges, then the sum diverges too. $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\log x dx}{x} = \left. \frac{ \log^{2} x}{2}  |^{\infty}_{1}\right.=\infty$. The integral diverges, hence the sum diverges too. Since the original sum is lower-bounded by this one, by comparison test it diverges too.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Since $|\sin n|\le 1$, and $\ln n \gt 1$ for $n\ge 3$, the $n$-th term of our sequence is greater than $\frac{1}{n}$ if $n\ge 3$. Now use the Comparison Test.

Comment: Got it thanks! That seems easier now